# How to mimic domain alias for Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

I have an Exchange 2013 server configured with multiple users and groups. Each user have their own email addresses (following no specific standard), so I don't sync with the email policy. Now, I want to add a second domain to the server (which is the easy part) - but how do I accept emails directed to the new domain to all users?

For an example, let's say that I currently have the domain **foo.com** with the users **Bob** and **John**:

**Bob** has the email addresses bobby@foo.com and bobo@foo.com. **John** has the email addresses john@foo.com, johnny@foo.com, j@foo.com and jim@foo.com.

Now, I want to add the domain **bar.com** to the server and allow both users to accept emails with their existing email addresses, but with **bar.com** as well. For instance **Bob** would be able to get mail into his mailbox addressed to either the addresses above or bobby@bar.com or bobo@bar.com.

In other servers this can be achieved by adding **bar.com** a domain alias, and that's that.

What I've already considered/tried:

- Manually modifying each user by copying each email address, modifying it with the new domain, and adding it to the user. This is no-go since I have plenty of users, and more than 1 additional domain to be added.
- Using EWS (Exchange Web Services) to modify/add the users email addresses also seems impossible, since it only supports retrieving the first 3 addresses for each user (EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress3).

Comment: Did you ever find a workable solution to this? Maybe one that also automatically adds the email domain aliases when new users are created also?

Comment: Nope. No solution :(

Answer (score 1):

My opinion would be to write a Powershell script that enumerates all the email addresses associated with a mailbox and replace the domain portion with your new domain. Since these are email addresses, it should be pretty easy to split the addresses at the '@' symbol, and then add the new smtp address to the mailbox.

Comment: I've now considered this, and while it seems like a solution, I fear that a user with, say 5 email addresses, and a total domains of 10 would get 50 or so email-addresses, and this would be a nightmare to get an overview of - and to administer. Perhaps it's possible to instead setup a rewrite rule or something (is there such a feature in Exchange)?